# GitLab 500 on group or group detail page

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have recently updated the GitLab version 11.11.8 to 13.2.6.

After the update, I am seeing an issue (500) while navigating to the group main, group detail or group member page. Other pages under the group work find.

here is log from production.log

I'm very new to GitLab and Ruby. Any comment is welcome.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "group_group_links" does not exist
LINE 8:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"group_group_links"'::regclass
                            ^
):
    1: - model_name = source.model_name.to_s.downcase
    2:
    3: - if can?(current_user, :"destroy_#{model_name}_member", source.members.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)) # rubocop: disable CodeReuse/ActiveRecord
    4:   - link_text = source.is_a?(Group) ? _('Leave group') : _('Leave project')
    5:   = link_to link_text, polymorphic_path([:leave, source, :members]),
    6:             method: :delete,

app/models/group.rb:601:in `members_from_self_and_ancestor_group_shares'
app/models/group.rb:345:in `members_with_parents'
app/models/group.rb:274:in `has_owner?'
app/models/group.rb:289:in `last_owner?'
app/policies/group_member_policy.rb:7:in `block in <class:GroupMemberPolicy>'
lib/declarative_policy/condition.rb:23:in `instance_eval'
lib/declarative_policy/condition.rb:23:in `compute'
lib/declarative_policy/condition.rb:44:in `block in pass?'
lib/declarative_policy/base.rb:303:in `cache'
lib/declarative_policy/condition.rb:44:in `pass?'
lib/declarative_policy/rule.rb:81:in `pass?'
lib/declarative_policy/step.rb:81:in `pass?'
lib/declarative_policy/runner.rb:101:in `block in run'
lib/declarative_policy/runner.rb:180:in `block in steps_by_score'
lib/declarative_policy/runner.rb:149:in `loop'
lib/declarative_policy/runner.rb:149:in `steps_by_score'
lib/declarative_policy/runner.rb:82:in `run'
lib/declarative_policy/runner.rb:60:in `pass?'
lib/declarative_policy/base.rb:234:in `block in allowed?'
lib/declarative_policy/base.rb:234:in `all?'
lib/declarative_policy/base.rb:234:in `allowed?'
lib/declarative_policy/base.rb:226:in `can?'
app/models/ability.rb:72:in `allowed?'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:200:in `can?'
app/views/shared/members/_access_request_links.html.haml:3
app/views/groups/_home_panel.html.haml:21
app/views/groups/show.html.haml:13
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:134:in `render'
app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:174:in `render_show_html'
app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in show'
app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:76:in `show'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:491:in `set_current_admin'
lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in `with_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:482:in `set_session_storage'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:55:in `with_locale'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:61:in `with_user_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:476:in `set_locale'
lib/gitlab/error_tracking.rb:50:in `with_context'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:541:in `sentry_context'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:469:in `block in set_current_context'
lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:52:in `block in use'
lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:52:in `use'
lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:20:in `with_context'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:462:in `set_current_context'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:140:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:51:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:23:in `call'
config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:9:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:60:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:12:in `call'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/241664

The issue now resolved after placing [20180902070406_create_group_group_links.rb](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/b86a9b14b6d43923decec049cf18d915c81d3e7c/db/migrate/20180902070406_create_group_group_links.rb) file under db/migrate/
then run

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```